# Setting up web geodatabase?

Tags: web-mapping, spatial-database, software-recommendations, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I need some advice regarding setting up a web map service/database. I need the database to have certain properties:

1. It can be displayed as a web map with certain layers that I made in QGIS. So that implies there should be a web link. I was looking at plug-ins like qgiscloud and qgis2web for this. The viewer can click on a polygon and all the information about the polygon should come up in a pop-up. Furthermore, there should also be an option of viewing a graph that shows statistics and changes in the attribute values of the polygons/rasters. And lastly, it would be nice if there is an option to show a simulation of changes in properties of the polygons/rasters.
2. On another website, I would like to create a form where selected people can input entries. When they submit these entries, the information should be sent onto the existing database and should automatically (with approval of an admin) create a QGIS layer reflecting the information. The new information should also be reflected on the web map service.

I am relatively experienced with programming, but I am not very sure how to set up such a database and display it on the web.

Can you make any recommendations for platforms/softwares that would enable me to perform these 2 functions?

Comment: If not too likely to generate opinions, I think this would be too broad because it is effectively asking for answers to many questions.

Comment: Hmm that is true, but then again I would like to have some direction and I don't see the concern with experts guiding a learner, regardless of by opinion or experience. Ultimately, the end product would help me to learn.

Comment: Just to help narrow things down, qgis2web can make a web map of your layers, with popups for the layers' data. However, it can't do any of the other things you require. If could therefore help you, but only as one of several disparate tools. I'd therefore possibly not recommend it in this case. You'd be better off with something which has client and server elements more closely integrated. This is, of course, an opinion.